# Bind sub crystal report

Tags: asp.net, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures, crystal-reports

hii i am new in crystal report can anyone help me to know..

How to bind **crystal  report** and **sub crystal report** using two datatable in one dataset

i Use [this](http://csharpdotnetfreak.blogspot.com/2009/07/subreports-in-crystal-reports-in-aspnet.html) to create a crystal Report. But Don't Know how to bind it using Database?

Comment: Above I mentioned a link,Please go through it.I followed the same concept as above.

Comment: we are trying to develop a solution for you.

Answer (score 0):

Right click the main report and select "Insert" and choose "SubReport...". Add the sub report and it will ask you to enter the name of the report. Finally it will a open Report Wizard which will allow you to add a database and its fields inside the sub report.

Try this

```
Dim objDataAdapter As New System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter(“SQL Query”, Connection)
            Dim objDataSet As New DataSet
            objDataAdapter.Fill(objDataSet, “Report Table”)

' CREATE THE XML FILE IN THE BASE DIRECTORY AND LOAD THE REPORT.

objDataSet.WriteXmlSchema(System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory() & Detail.xsd)
Report.Load(System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory() & Report.rtp)

Report.SetDataSource(objDataSet)
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply but i already used SubReport and add all required fields from databse.My question is how to bind crystal report & sub crystal report from code behind.